# Restricting generic type in extensions in Dart

Tags: dart, generics

I'm trying to add an extension method on lists with items extending a specific class. I thought this would work:

```
abstract class Foo {
  bool bar();
}

extension FooListExtension on List<T extends Foo> {
  List<T> bar() {
    return where((e) => e.bar()).toList();
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error from analyzer:

```
The name 'T' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument
```

I was wondering if there is any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is the following since you need to apply the generic requirements on the extension itself. You can then use the generic (e.g. `T`) in your extension:

```
abstract class Foo {
  bool bar();
}

extension FooListExtension<T extends Foo> on List<T> {
  List<T> bar() {
    return where((e) => e.bar()).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't figure it out! Thank you so much.